# Is there a way to evaluate de natural density of numbers of the form $ax^2-by^2$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I was trying to evaluate the density of numbers of the form $5x²-y²$ and ended up pondering about this question. Can we always find the natural density of numbers of the form $ax^2-by^2$, where $(a,b)=1$ and are positive integers, and if so, how?

Comment: the values expressed by your form are a completely multiplicative set; it represents $1,$    multiplication comes from Gauss composition.  Oh, the density will be zero; the count up to large positive $x$  will be asymptotic to a constant times $\frac{x}{\sqrt{\log x}}$

Comment: Meanwhile, for your indefinite $ax^2 - b y^2$  there is a positive density if $ab$ is a square (the form factors),  but otherwise density zero.